# How to read a text file to a list array?

Tags: r

I just started coding in R-Lang and I was wondering what the best way to read a plan text file is? I am looking for something like this pseudo-code:

```
data = new List();
data = file.readall("myfile.txt")
close

foreach (a in data) {
  print(a)
}
```

pretty simple text, I read the tutorials but dont understand how R's file access works, it looks very much different to anything im used to.. I'm unsure what args to use.

Comment: what have you tried? type "read R file" in google|bing :) and check the first link.

Comment: I've tried what i've seen in tutorials, such as: data <- read.table("myfile.txt") wont work, also this doesn't answer how to have it as a list array

Comment: The standard way of reading text data is using `read.table`. Please explain more clearly what you want to do, and why the standard R solution is not satisfactory.

Comment: I can't really explain more clearly than I have + the pseudo code :/ i just want to read an entire flat text file in to a list array. I have tried basic file io stuff like this: con <- file("myfile.txt", "r") seek(con, 3) # step over the 3 initial bytes, the BOM foo <- read.table(con) close(con) but i get this error
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 2 did not have 6 elements
Calls: read.table -> scan why does it not work when it comes directly from the tutorial

Comment: Please provide us with the text file, probably pasting the first 5 lines in your question above will be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pseudocode in R style:

```
dat = readLines("file.txt")
```

Now `dat` is a vector where each line in the file is an element in the vector. R is a functionally oriented language, so this performs a given function on each element:

```
l = lapply(dat, process_line)
```

Where `process_line` is the function that processes each line. The result is a list of processed lines. To put them into a `data.frame`:

```
do.call("rbind", l)
```

Or use `ldply` from the `plyr` package to do this in one go:

```
require(plyr)
ldply(dat, process_line)
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
  test.txt <- read.table("d:/test.txt", header=T)
```